# Filter list by enum

Tags: java, enums

I have a list of String

```
List<String> matType = {"window","door","room","kitchen","bedroom"}
```

and an enum

```
class Enum Type{
    WIN("window"),
    DOOR("door");

    private String type;

    private Type(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

My final list should be `matType : {"window", "door"}`.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: i tried this solution:
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/filtering-out-unique-values-from-a-list-in-java

but the .equals("off") must be a list for me

Comment: You can create a ```list, set or map``` of your existing ```enum values``` and then use that to filter out the invalid ones from your array using ```Java Streams```.

Comment: I do not see any question mark in your post. What did you try already ? (please share what you've tried and not the website from where you find the solution).

Comment: try Type.WIN == Type.valueOf("window")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple implementation:

```
 List<String> matchingTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String myType : matType) {
       for (Type type : Type.values()) {
          if (type.getType().equals(myType)) {
             matchingTypes.add(myType);
          }
        }
     }
```

Implementation using stream:

```
    List<String> matchingTypes = Arrays.stream(Type.values())
            .map(Type::getType)
            .filter(matType::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your inner for-each loop does not have the correct variable type on the left hand side. It should be `Type type`, and then in your if statement, it should say `type.getType().equals(myType)`.

Comment: True, now It's correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse each list value as an enum and keep those which could be parsed:

```
final List<String> matType = {"window","door","room","kitchen","bedroom"};
final List<String> result = matType.stream()
    .filter(t -> {
      try {
        Type.valueOf(t); // throws an exception for invalid names
        return true;
      } catch (final Exception ex) {
        return false;
      }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if you are filtering with your enum lots of times, it is probably worthwhile to build a set with your enum's names *once* and then re-use:

```
class Enum Type {
    WIN("window"),
    DOOR("door");

    private static final Set<String> typeNames = values().stream()
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

    private final String type;

    private Type(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    private boolean isValidName(final String name) {
      return typeNames.contains(name);
    }
}

final List<String> matType = {"window","door","room","kitchen","bedroom"};
final List<String> result = matType.stream()
    .filter(Type::isValidName);
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```